# .click() jquery function not working. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/gmz73oew/

So I'm trying to make it so that on the click of the button the height of the div grows. I've got this animation working by itself smoothly but I'm having issues when I try to make it happen via clicking the button.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function(){
      $("#maBlock").animate({ 
         height: "950px",
         top: "0px",
      }, 2000 );
    });
  }
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Syntax error, miss a `)` at the end. You should open dev-tool and see is there pops out any error before ask.

Comment: Keep your developer console open!  You're missing the `)` after the "ready" handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a bracket and a semicolon to the end, to close the ones that `$(document).ready(function() {` opened:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("#maBlock").animate({
            height: "950px",
            top: "0px",
        }, 2000);
    });
});     //here you need the ');'
```

Comment: Thank you, and the others for posting. I've fixed the error, however, the animation is still not working :) Any other ideas?

Comment: As you see on my fiddle it is working now, could you make another fiddle, with the `);`, still not working? @seanki

Comment: Great! You could accept this answer by clicking the tick next to it on the left, under the upvote and downvote arrows @seanki

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code
replace your js code below snippet of code

[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmz73oew/4/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
      $("#maBlock").animate({ 
         height: "950px",
         top: "0px",
      }, 2000 );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot bracket and semicolon in the last row

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('ciao');
$("#button1").click(function(){

  $("#maBlock").animate({ 
     height: "950px",
     top: "0px",
  }, 2000 );
});
});//<----- this
```